# How to create my own JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

How to create my own JavaScript object and how can I check whether my custom object is present in my page or not?

What is the difference between JavaScript function calling using an ordinary JS file and creating a custom JavaScript object?

For Example:
We can check the Jquery object by using the following JavaScript code:

```
if(window.Jquery != 'undefined'){
    // Jquery Object is Present
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You create JavaScript objects/namespaces like this:

```
var FooQuery = {
  hello: function() { alert('hello') }
};

FooQuery.hello(); // alerts "hello"
```

Or like this (to have `FooQuery` instances):

```
function FooQuery() {
  this.hello = function() { alert('hello') };
}

new FooQuery().hello(); // alerts "hello"
```

Or like this:

```
function FooQuery() {}
FooQuery.prototype.hello = function() { alert('hello') };

new FooQuery().hello(); // alerts "hello"
```

You check whether it's available like this:

```
if(window.FooQuery) { /* ... */ }
```

Or like this:

```
if(typeof window.FooQuery !== 'undefined') { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: This is the way Doug Crockford does it, so it can't be bad! +1

Comment: @AutomatedTester: that statement does not compute.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create my own JavaScript object

var foo = {};

> and how can I check whether my custom object is present in my page or not?

if (foo) { /* … */ }

> What is the difference between JavaScript function 
>   calling using an ordinary JS file and creating a custom JavaScript object?

A function cannot "call a file". It could dynamically generate an HTML script element with a src attribute, and append it to the page. That would cause the resource to be loaded as normal.

> We can check the Jquery object by using the following JavaScript code:

No. That would test to make sure that whatever window.Jquery was, it was not the string with the value "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own JavaScript object given by below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
objPerson    =    new Object();
objPerson.fname    =    "Milap";
objPerson.lname    =    "Patel";
objPerson.age    =    "24";
document.write(objPerson.age);
</script>
```

objectname = new Object();
will create JavaScript object named "objectname".

fname and lname are methods and we can assign values to object,
objPerson.age    =    "24";

Answer (score -1):

You can create a JS object using JSON:

```
var someObject = {
    property1: 'my first property',
    property2: 'my second property',
    property3: 12345,
    property4: ['first list item','second list item']
};
```

Using Dojo, you could create an object as follows:

```
dojo.declare('gumbo.objects.first',null,{
    property1: 'my first property',
    property2: 'my second property'
});
```

There are many other ways of doing this, it all depends on what your preferences are and which libraries you use.

Comment: That *ain't* JSON. That's just a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: … and not one that would conform to the JSON specification if it was  string data.

Comment: You're right. Using JSON it would be
var someObject = {
  "property1" = "my first property"
};

Comment: @Emmster: no, using JSON it would be `var someObject = eval('({ "property1": "my first property" })')`. Get it? JSON is a data interchange format (think *"string"*). It happens to be legal notation  for a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: That's not what http://www.json.org/js.html implies, unless I completely misunderstand it.